# Bug in treeview display when editing cell

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I have **two bugs** when I use a `treeview`, here's what happen :

**BUG 1** : Not validate changes

*How to create the bug* :
Let's suppose I want to edit the cell "Id" in my treview.[image: picture 1]

I enter something else :

[image: picture 2]

But I change my mind, I don't want to edit this item, so instead of clicking on enter and validate,I click left on something else, everything seems ok, I'm back to picture one, but if I click to edit the "Id" cell again, i'm directly back at picture 2, and "Id-Edit" is show to me, it means the cancel of the edit didn't work well ...

**BUG 2** : The change of value

It happens rarely but happens, when I click on a celle to edit it, this cell take the text of another cell, here's an example :

[image: picture 3]

The "Id" take the text of another cell when I edit it, but if I cancel the edit, eveything is back to normal again, like in picture one.

Here's the **code** that I use for my treeview :

```
    public class DatabaseStructureView extends TreeView<Object> {

    TreeItem<Object> root;

    public DatabaseStructureView() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DatabaseStructureView.fxml"));

        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }

        this.setEditable(true);
        this.setCellFactory((TreeView<Object> param) -> new TextFieldTreeCellImpl());
        root = new TreeItem<>();
        this.setRoot(root);
        setShowRoot(false);
        root.setExpanded(true);
    }

    private final class TextFieldTreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<Object> {

        private TextField textField;

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();

            if (textField == null) {
                createTextField();
            }
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(getString());
            setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getString());
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(getString());
                    setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                }
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                    if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                        commitEdit(getDatabase(textField.getText()));
                    } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private Database getDatabase(String text) {
            return new Database(text);
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param db
     */
    public void setDatabase(Database db) {
        TreeItem<Object> dbRoot = new TreeItem<>(db);
        dbRoot.setExpanded(true);

        db.getVariables().stream().forEach((var) -> {
            dbRoot.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(var));
        });

        if (!root.getChildren().contains(dbRoot)) {
            root.getChildren().add(dbRoot);
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param dbs
     */
    public void setDatabases(List<Database> dbs) {
        dbs.stream().forEach((db) -> {
            setDatabase(db);
        });
    }
}
```

As you may see, my tree view is not fill with `String` but with an object that I create, and is `Database` , that's why I use `Object` type. I think my problem comes from the update function, but don't know why.

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `startEdit()` method, you need to set the text of the text field to the correct value:

```
    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();

        if (textField == null) {
            createTextField();
        }

        textField.setText(getString());

        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.selectAll();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves my BUG 1, can you explain to me what is the function setText ?

Comment: Does the second bug still appear? A `Cell` has both text and a graphic. In your case the graphic is a text field and is only displayed when the cell is in editing mode. The `setText(...)` method sets the text for the cell to display. `textField.setText(...)` sets the text displayed in the text field. The problem you had was that when the user cancelled, then edited again, the text field's text was unchanged between the cancelation and going back into edit mode.

Comment: Yes the bug 2 is still here, thanks for your help, not the first time you help me on this ^^

Comment: Updated answer. I think the updated version will fix both bugs.

Comment: Yes it works, but I don't understand why i have to set the textfiels to the correct value ? If you can help me to understand what was wrong, anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: Well, if you don't set it to the correct value, it will just display the last value it had, which might not be the correct one. For the first bug, it still has the last value that it had when the user was previously editing. The second bug manifests when cells are reused from one item to another (e.g. if you scroll), so if a text field was previously used in the cell to edit one item and is then used to edit another, it won't have been properly updated.